# Unity scaling an object when duplicating (not wanted)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a mining game, where you have a rest area, and a mine area (all of this stuff works well) but when I "hire a new worker" the main miner clones, and is put in the starting area. When I clone the main miner, the cloned miner's size goes to 6k something something.

```
public void moreMiners(){
        if (gm.Diamonds >= gm.mmcost){
            gm.Diamonds -= gm.mmcost;
            GameObject newplr = GameObject.Instantiate(plr);
            newplr.gameObject.transform.localPosition = plr.transform.position;
 
        }
    }
```

duplicating code ^

help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "**plr**" reference is the original [Prefab](https://GameObject.Instantiate(plr,plr.transform.position);) from your assets folder and not from your scene, then what you can do is to check your original prefab inside your assets folder and see if the scale is the one that you want to have.

Also when you [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) an object you can parse the position too as a parameter like this:

```
GameObject.Instantiate(plr,position);
```